# Make CSS grid or flex item equal size with stretched separator between

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I try to build a dynamic toolbar where:

- The number of tools is dynamic
- All tools should have the same width (based on the widest one)
- Tools can be separated by a separator that takes all the space available (stretched)
- The separator can be placed anywhere
- The html can't be changed

Expected output (given `BBB` the widest tool):

```sh
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————
| A |BBB| CC|            SEPARATOR              | D |
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

#### Flex

I tried with the `flex` method, I can't combine all the rules:

- Either the separator takes all the space but tools width are not equal:

```sh
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————
|A|BBB|CC|       SEPARATOR                        |D|
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.separator {
  width: 100%;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">BBB</div>
  <div class="item">CC</div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
</nav>
```

- Either all tools (including the separator) have the same width:

```sh
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————
|    A    |   BBB   |    CC   | SEPARATOR |    D    |
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.separator {
  flex: 1;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">BBB</div>
  <div class="item">CC</div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
</nav>
```

#### Grid

With the `grid` system, I can't get the separator without specifying a `grid-template-columns`, which I want to avoid. I need something dynamic.

```css
nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  text-align: center;
}

.separator {
  justify-self: stretch;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">BBB</div>
  <div class="item">CC</div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
</nav>
```

I'm open to JavaScript solutions if there is no CSS solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: what is the issue with both solution (you are showing) where you *already* have equal width?

Comment: Thanks for putting a detailed question, but I am not getting what is the expected output? and what is the issue with your codes?

Comment: Why not sperator is generated by css? instead to make a html tag

Comment: @TemaniAfif the separator should be the only one not to have equal width, which I can't get for now.

Comment: `flex: 2;` for the seprator and it will be bigger (or any bigger number)

Comment: @palaѕн the expected output is the first example I put in my question. All tools should have the same size EXCEPT the separator that should take all the space available. I will detail my question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I need the full available space, not twice or thrice the size of the tools.

Comment: then define clearly *equal width*. 100px is equal to 100px and 200px is also equal to 200px

Comment: The items before the separtor  should be in one div then separtor after them then another div to hold other items after separator, then you cut all elements inside nav and put a div with style display:flex and paste the cuted elements inside this flex div, now nav should be one line and the 2 div's other than the separator can be easily solved as you want.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I clarified my question. When I mean *equal width*, I mean all tools width should align to the widest tool width.

Comment: @MostafaHarb I don't have access to the html, that's why I try to find a CSS only solution.

Comment: the nav is full page width?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, but it's not important. The layout should work no matter the `nav` size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

via javascript , you can loop through .item and look for the widest , then update a custom css property.

possible example via js and flex

```js
var bigW = "0";

for (let e of document.querySelectorAll("nav .item")) {
  elW = e.offsetWidth;
  if (elW > bigW) {
    bigW = elW;
  }
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--myW", bigW + 1 + "px");
}
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  background: #e8e8e8;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  min-width: var(--myW, 3em);
  text-align: center;
}

.separator {
  flex: 1;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

nav div+div {
  border-left: solid;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">BBB</div>
  <div class="item">CC</div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
</nav>
```

---

edit from a comment  below

```js
var bigW = "0";

for (let e of document.querySelectorAll("nav > div")) {
  elW = e.offsetWidth;
  if (elW < 7) {// includes partially possible border and padding, mind it
    e.style.flexGrow = 1;
  } else if (elW > bigW) {
    bigW = elW;
  }
}
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--myW", bigW + 1 + "px");
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  background: #e8e8e8;
}

.item {
  min-width: var(--myW, 0);
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.separator {
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">BBBBBBBB</div>
  <!--<div class="separator"></div>-->
  <div class="item">CC</div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think also that it's the best JavaScript approach. I wait a bit to see if someone finds a pure CSS solution, otherwise I will validate your answer.

Comment: This is a great solution IMHO. A bit of JS does the trick. I would only add that an HTML separator is not necessary. `margin-left: auto` on the last item should be enough. https://jsfiddle.net/6d1jn8qv/

Comment: @Michael_B agreed, seems like html could not  be modified ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I still can't find a way in pure CSS. I need either to change the HTML (grouping tools) or to add JavaScript (your approach), so I validate your answer. I just adapted my code using a `reduce` instead (to avoid the global variable): `Array.from(items).reduce((widest, el) => Math.max(widest, el.offsetWidth), 0)`

Comment: @soywod you could also insert it in the if statement and set the flexgrow there , it would allow a few separator i believe : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YzXoQyO